# Show that $R/ I=\{x+I\mid x\in R\}$ is a Ring if $I$ is an Ideal and it isn't if $I$ is only a subring

Tags: abstract-algebra

As the title says I have to show that for $R$ a commutative ring with neutral element, $ R/ I=\{x+I\mid x\in R\}$ is a ring if $I$ is an ideal and it isn't if $I$ is only a subring.
It's the first time I am hearing about Rings so it's not that easy for me.

I am proving the Ring conditions and the first one is that it has to be an abelian group.
Let's start with the associative property:
We take $x,y,z \in R/I$:
We have to show that $(x+I+y+I)+z+I=x+I+(y+I+z+I)$

For example on the left hand side I guess that I have to do $((x+y)+I)+z+I$ and then $(x+y+z)+I$ and same with the other side but what gives  me the right to write $(x+I+y+I)=((x+y)+I)$, why can I take $x$ and $y$ together and then the same logic with $z$ and also (this might be very trivial) why is the $I$ only counted once and not 3 times.

And also, what does the Ideal give me in this specific case that the subring does not?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: As far as the addition goes, all you need is that $I$ is an additive subgroup. But look at the multiplication, that's where "ideal" comes into play.

Comment: My main problem is why: $(x+I)+(y+I)=(x+y)+I$ and why $(x+I)*(y+I)=(x*y)+I$

Comment: Annalisa, these are the definitions of the operations on $R/I$. And the point is that the multiplication is only well-defined if $I$ is an ideal - rather like in group theory, where the operation on $G/N$ is only well-defined if $N$ is a normal subgroup.